# Log in with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory-module

Our client needs to pre-authenticate with AD before common Sitecore built-in authentication (they don't need the AD users in Sitecore). We switched on "Log in with Azure Active Directory" at our CM App Service instance's `Authentication / Authorization` setting. It works well at the begining - redirects to AD login screen and after successful AD login, redirects back to Sitecore login (`/sitecore/login`). But after a successful Sitecore login, we get a strange redirect to `/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx?item=%2fsitecore%2fclient%2fApplications%2fLaunchpad+(route%3a+%7b*pathInfo%7d)&user={ADUSER}&site=shell`

Please help, how is it possible to make it work?

Why "overrides" the AD authentication the Sitecore one?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore?

Comment: We had to implement the oauth2 workflow against the Azure AD tenant using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt. There were some issues to find the proper pipeline to process in and also take care of Unicorn control panel (if is in use). I hope Sitecore will provide lightweight solution to use with Azure AD.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue, with Sitecore 9 as a PAAS on Azure.
There seems to be some conflict between webforms authentication/authorization in Sitecore and what Azure uses.
I did'nt find a direct solution, but as a work around i used an HTTP auth module to intercept and challenge using "Basic" or "Digest" authentication/authorization.
 [Link Here](https://www.alexlindgren.com/archive/password-protecting-azure-websites-revisited/)

Now this comes with it's own risks,i.e having credentials in clear text in the web.config and also using "Basic" authentication/authorisation sends clear text over the wire (use "Digest" option for encrypted transmission). But as I mentioned, this is a work around which gets things going, until a more elegant solution is found, or Sitecore fixes how they do forms authentication within an Azure context.